# {Equaling objects} "where is my object reference on ?" c#

Tags: c#

I have one `class` named 'human' and 2 `objects` ( `obj1 , obj2` ).
and I have written below code

```
class human
{
    public static int x;
    public readonly int id;

    public human()
    {
        x++;
        id = x;
    }

    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id = " + id);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        human obj1 = new human();
        human obj2 = new human();

        obj2 = obj1;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I know when I write that code ->> `human obj2 = obj1;`

`obj2` reference on `obj1` in `heap`

but in my code with this ->> `human obj2 = new human();`

and do that ->> `obj2 = obj1;`

is `obj2` will update values in his `object` with `obj1`'s values ??

or `obj2` will reference on `obj1`

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to try displaying `id` of obj1 and obj2 in Console. That would help you understand what is happening

Comment: Small tip: use `.GetHashCode()` to get the unique object identifier. You might want to use it to understand whether `obj1` and `obj2` are pointing to the same object or not

Comment: Have you tried it? Anyway `obj1` and `obj2` will not actually "be" the instance of the human class. They'll be a pointer to an instance of the human class. So when you do `obj2 = obj1` you copy the pointer (so they now point to the same instance of `obj2`, there is no copying of values from `obj1` to `obj2`. `obj1` is not referenced anymore so will at some point be collected by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a `class` both `obj1` and `obj2` will reference the same object in memory (as they are reference types). A `human` object with an id of `1`

Answer (score 1):

C# has value types and reference types. A value type directly stores the data, whereas a reference type contains a *reference* to the data. A class is a reference type.

Where you have:

```
human obj1 = new human();
human obj2 = new human();
```

you are creating two new variables containing references to different new instances of `human`.

When you do:

```
obj2 = obj1;
```

You are saying "take the reference that obj1 contains and assign it to obj2". This means obj1 *and* obj2 are now both referencing the *same instance* that obj1 initially referenced.

If you had, for example, some public property called `Name`, and you set:

```
obj1.Name = "Bob"
```

and then you accessed `obj2.Name`, you will find that you get the value "Bob", because both `obj1` and `obj2` are referencing the same instance.

In your example, you will notice that `obj1` and `obj2` both have the same `Id`.